# Deploy a custom webpart to SharePoint2013

Tags: deployment, sharepoint-2013, web-parts

I've recently made the transition to the SP13 environment, but I'm having trouble deploying my custom web part. I know this can be done automatically with visual studios, but we do not have access to this in production. I'd prefer to avoid the Microsoft Powershell recommendation, as we do not have a way to build the CAB file. I've also tried editing the web.config and copying the .dll into the appropriate bin folder, but the web part never shows up in /_layouts/15/newdwp.aspx

How do you deploy a custom web part in SharePoint 2013? If you know of more than 1 solution besides visual studio, please share.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to get the sources of your webpart and recompile it for SharePoint 2013 (use v15 of sharepoint dll) if the webpart is manipulating SharePoint objects.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/cbc67f47-b58e-4384-b87f-fd57aa7f2721/migrate-custom-sharepoint-2007-webpart-to-sharepoint-2013?forum=appsforsharepoint

And in the rare case you don't have access to the source and the dll doesn't need to be recompiled, you will need to migrate also ".dwp" or ".webpart" file and all resources (images/css/...) used by your webpart.

".dwp" or ".webpart" (regarding the type of your webpart) file has to be uploaded in "http://your_sitecollection/_catalogs/wp/"